# Understanding use of memcpy on memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, free

Looking at the source code for [`e2fsprogs`](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs) and wanting to understand the use of internal memory routines. Allocating and freeing.

More to the point why use `memcpy` instead of direct handling?

### Allocate

For example [ext2fs_get_mem](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/657715deb85ce5cdea7bc2cc11dde2058d73f4c9/lib/ext2fs/ext2fs.h#L1872) is:

```c
/*
 *  Allocate memory.  The 'ptr' arg must point to a pointer.
 */
_INLINE_ errcode_t ext2fs_get_mem(unsigned long size, void *ptr)
{
    void *pp;

    pp = malloc(size);
    if (!pp)
        return EXT2_ET_NO_MEMORY;
    memcpy(ptr, &pp, sizeof (pp));
    return 0;
}
```

I guess the use of a local variable is as not to invalidate the passed `ptr` in case of `malloc` error.

1. Why `memcpy` instead of setting `ptr` to `pp` on success?

### Free

The memory is copied to a local variable, then freed, then `memcpy` on the passed pointer to pointer. As the allocation uses `memcpy` I *guess* it has to do some juggling on free as well.

2. It can not free directly?
3. And what does the last `memcpy` do? Isn't `sizeof(p)` size of int here?

```c
/*
 * Free memory.  The 'ptr' arg must point to a pointer.
 */
_INLINE_ errcode_t ext2fs_free_mem(void *ptr)
{
    void *p;

    memcpy(&p, ptr, sizeof(p));
    free(p);
    p = 0;
    memcpy(ptr, &p, sizeof(p));
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Example of use:

`ext2_file_t` is defined as:

```c
typedef struct ext2_file *ext2_file_t;
```

where [ext2_file has](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/657715deb85ce5cdea7bc2cc11dde2058d73f4c9/lib/ext2fs/fileio.c#L23), amongst other members, `char *buf`.

In [`dump.c : dump_file()`](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/657715deb85ce5cdea7bc2cc11dde2058d73f4c9/debugfs/dump.c#L100)

Here we have:

```c
    ext2_file_t e2_file;
    retval = ext2fs_file_open(current_fs, ino, 0, &e2_file);
```

It calls [`ext2fs_file_open()`](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/657715deb85ce5cdea7bc2cc11dde2058d73f4c9/lib/ext2fs/fileio.c#L43) which do:

```c
    ext2_file_t     file;
    retval = ext2fs_get_mem(sizeof(struct ext2_file), &file);
    retval = ext2fs_get_array(3, fs->blocksize, &file->buf);
```

And the free routine is for example:

```c
    if (file->buf)
        ext2fs_free_mem(&file->buf);
    ext2fs_free_mem(&file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign directly to the `ptr` parameter, as this is a local variable. `memcpy`ing to `ptr` actually writes to where the pointer points to. Compare the following usage code:

```
struct SomeData* data;
//ext2fs_get_mem(256, data); // wrong!!!
ext2fs_get_mem(256, &data);
//                  ^ (!)
```

You would achieve exactly the same with a double pointer indirection:

```
_INLINE_ errcode_t ext2fs_get_mem_demo(unsigned long size, void** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(size);
    return *ptr ? 0 : EXT2_ET_NO_MEMORY;
}
```

but this variant requires the pointer being passed to to be of type `void*`, which is avoided by the original variant:

```
void* p;
ext2fs_get_mem_demo(256, &p);
struct SomeData* data = p;
```

Note: One additional variable and one additional line of code (or at very least one would need a cast)...

Note, too, that in the usage example `ext_file_t` should be a `typedef` to a pointer type to make this work correctly (or `uintptr_t`) or at least have a pointer as its first member (address of struct and address of its first member are guaranteed to be the same in C).

Comment: Thought one could assign the *address* of the local `pp` to the address of `ptr` - as that is where the pointer points to. (As in: `static inline void *xmalloc(size_t size){ void *p = malloc(size); /*Err check*/; return p; }`) And as the type def is `struct ext2_file *` and not `struct ext2_file` the argument by `&p` is in effect `**p`. But it's starting to sink in ... not quite there yet. Have to read your answer a couple of more times and think :P

Comment: A variant what you could have done internally: `void** pp = (void**) ptr; *pp = malloc();` They might have chosen the `memcpy` variant to avoid any issues with strict aliasing rules, though this should not be an issue here. Read multiple times? Well, even *edited*, as history reveals... The main point about accepting a pointer to pointer as simple `void*` pointer is to avoid necessity of a cast (`get_mem(&data)` vs. `get_mem((void**)&data)`), but you need to handle the single pointer representing a double one by some appropriate means internally, one of is `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

> /* The 'ptr' arg must point to a pointer. */

can be read as "The ptr can point to pointer to ANYTHING".

It is a very simple malloc-wrapper in a library; to be useful it has to work for any type. So `void *` is the argument.

With a real type the function looks like this, with direct pointer assignment:

```
int g(unsigned long size, int **ptr)
{
    void *pp;

    pp = malloc(size);
    if (!pp)
        return 1;
    *ptr = pp;
    return 0;
}
```

The same `*ptr = pp` gives a **invalid-void error** with `void *ptr` as argument decalration. Somehow disappointing, but then again it is called `void *`, not `any *`.

With `void **ptr` there is a **type warning** like:

```
expected 'void **' but argument is of type 'int **'
```

So memcpy to the rescue. It looks like even without optimization, the call is replaced by a quadword MOV.